# Laravel 4 - Reverse Morpth - Relation

Tags: laravel, models, database-relations

I need some help with my models.

I have "Nodes" and "Categories". And i want to create "Menus" that have Nodes and Categories.

In morpth relation we had nodes and categories that had menus and NOT the reverse. Can anyone help me with the models?

Comment: Where is the code, please post here.

Comment: i dont have any code yet... it's only theoretic the question

Comment: Because there is no code, I'm not 100% sure what you are asking for, but it really sounds like what you actually need is a many to many relationship rather than a polymorphic relationship.